# how to simulate any command to see what would happen before actually executing it?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I would like to know how to simulate a command before running it, to see what the output would look like.

Comment: This is logically absurd. Read the `man` page for the command.

Comment: `mv` can be simulated with `ls`. That's about the only one I can think of.

Comment: `rsync`, `rename`, and some `apt-get` commands also allow for simulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are referring to is a "dry run", but there is no way to run *all* commands like this. You would have to check the manual pages on a command-by-command basis.

If you want to run potentially harmful commands just to see the outcome, I would recommending looking into [virtualizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualization) your OS and load files on it. This would be beneficial to you because it would allow you to take checkpoints/snapshots (terminology is different per virtualization program) which you can revert to at any time. This would allow you to run whatever commands you want on whatever files you want, see what happens, and if you don't like it, revert to your checkpoint. Virtualization is popular for software development environments because they offer reproducible and disposable machines.

Comment: so this "dry run" wont work for everything, I guess i'll be running some virtualbox then.

Comment: Correct. This is because some commands permanently modify files or make calls to external systems you wouldn't have control over reverting the changes on (Ex: you can't dry-run sending an e-mail because you can't unsend it). This is called "not being [idempotent](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/glossary.html)". If you plan to do this often, I would recommend scripting it. Consider looking into Ansible/Vagrant or something of the sort.